# Why isn't this variable being set although it is set in my .emacs?

Tags: init-file, variables

In my `init.el` file I have the following line `(setq js2-basic-offset 2)`

The last line in my `.init.el` file is

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
         (lambda ()
           (message "Welcome home %s" (user-login-name))))
```

When I start emacs and go to the `*Messages*` buffer, I see:

```
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/.mc-lists.el (source)...done
[yas] Prepared just-in-time loading of snippets successfully.
Welcome home user
```

However, when I do `C-h v js2-basic-offset` I get

```
js2-basic-offset is a variable defined in ‘js2-mode.el’.
Its value is 4

  This variable is an alias for ‘js-indent-level’.

Documentation:
Number of spaces for each indentation step in ‘js-mode’.

You can customize this variable
```

If I go to my `init.el` file and re-load it, the variable gets set to it's correct value of 2.

Does anybody have any solution for this issue?

Comment: You probably require the `js-mode` after setting `js2-basic-offset`, thus that it overwrites your value. Put a `(require 'js-mode)` before setting the value and see whether that resolves the issue. Note that this always requires the mode, wheter you you it or not, causing probably longer start time.

Comment: Looking at the source of `js2-mode` I found that `js2-basic-offset` is alias for `js-indent-level`. So setting the latter value may also help.

Comment: Check that you don't have a `customize`d value being evaluated after your `setq` form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
>   This variable is an alias for ‘js-indent-level’.
> ```

That's the clue. If you're running Emacs ≥25 then js2-mode defines `js2-basic-offset` as an [alias of the variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Aliases.html#index-defvaralias-809) `js-indent-level`. At the point where the variable is made an alias, any value that it had is forgotten. Only the value of the base variable (`js-indent-level`) matters.

If you set it later then the assignment dereferences the alias: once the alias is in place, `(setq js2-basic-offset 2)` is equivalent to `(setq js-indent-level 2)`.

So set `js-indent-level` in addition to `js2-basic-offset`, or instead if you don't care about versions of Emacs older than 25.